# iotedge not found in the /etc or /usr bin

Tags: yocto, azure-iot-edge

I have just built the iotedge using yocto for my embedded linux board and flashed the image but I cant see the iotedge inside the /etc or /usr/bin or /bin
Where could possibly be its location.

I have already included the relevant meta-rust and meta-virtualization with correct branches.This is my portion of build log showing no issue in iotedge-daemon building.

https://paste.in/4qxjAc

it has all the final step of do_install in rootfs but i am still not able to see iotedge inside the root file system after i flashed and booted with the built image.

please advise

Comment: is it added to the image?

Comment: Are you following this githubrepo ? https://github.com/Azure/meta-iotedge See also the blog: https://kevinsaye.wordpress.com/2021/07/09/yocto-linux-running-the-long-term-support-version-of-azure-iot-edge/

Comment: its working now , i flashed the wrong the image

Comment: Can you add and verify the answer? Thanks